# Python Installation Troubleshooting

Tags: python-3.x, failed-installation

I am struggling to install Python. I am running Windows 8.1 . Python used to run OK on my PC but I refreshed Windows recently and now have to install it again. I did delete the Python folder before I attempt installation and also made sure an older version was not installed. When I start the IDLE, about 9 IDLE windows open together with the last one which has a script in it :

```
try:
    import idlelib.PyShell
except ImportError:
    # IDLE is not installed, but maybe PyShell is on sys.path:
    try:
        from . import PyShell
    except ImportError:
        raise
    else:
        import os
        idledir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(PyShell.__file__))
        if idledir != os.getcwd():
            # We're not in the IDLE directory, help the subprocess find run.py
            pypath = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', '')
            if pypath:
                os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = pypath + ':' + idledir
            else:
                os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = idledir
        PyShell.main()
else:
    idlelib.PyShell.main()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have not read of this problem before. That file is Lib/idlelib/idle.pyw.  Are you starting with the Start menu icon (if that means anything on 8.1  -- I use Win 7).  If not, how?  When you say 'open', do you mean in Idle editor windows?  If so, edit question to list the files opened (see the title bar).

Comment: Suggestion: delete $HOME/.idlerc, where $HOME (on Win 7), would be c:/user/Arne (or whatever user name you use).

Comment: Hi, yes these are 9 IDLE edit windows. I tried the delete of the .idlerc folder, but it did not help. I am invoking it from a win8 startmenu program, so I tried to do it via the normal windows 8 interface and it works from there, thank you for pointing me in the right direction - at least I can now use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a complete uninstall of the program and reinstall it. Make sure you also have all windows updates. Just sounds like a bad/corrupted install.

Comment: I have uninstall ed and reinstalled various times. I also tried versions 3.4.1 alternating with 3.4.2. Every time making sure I also deleted the Python34 folder. I also ran the Microsoft installation fixer utility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried python 2.7.9? Still sounds like something is corrupted. Have you also downloaded python 3.x again on another machine and brought it over?